# Using Python Shell with any text editor

Tags: python, sublimetext

I use Sublime Text and am using the terminal to run my code.

I would prefer to use the Python Shell to run my code, as it has color and is not so hard to look at.

Is there any easy way to do this other than saving then opening in IDLE?

Comment: `ipython` makes a nice development environment and it will run the text editor of your choice.

Comment: You can run the code right in Sublime.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ctrl-b` to run your python in sublime. If you want to use a different interpreter you can customise under `Tools` -> `Build System`

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you check out [IPython](http://ipython.org/). You can run it through your terminal or through an IPython Notebook in your browser.

Comment: I don't think IPython has support for native desktop apps when running in the browser, like a Pygame program for example.

Answer (score 3):

Stick with Sublime text. It's a popular text editor with syntax highlighting for several different programming languages. Here's what you need to do:

1. Press Ctrl + Shift + P to bring up command palette and enter "python".
2. Choose the option that says something like "Set syntax to Python".
3. Enter Python code then Ctrl + Shift + B to build the project.
4. Code will run below in another view(you will probably be able to move it to the side).

This is the standard procedure for a python setup in sublime text, but you may need to install
SublimeREPL for python in order to get user input. Just give it a Google search.

Comment: The OP is already asking about Sublime Text, so I'm not sure how the "Try sublime text" fits. Otherwise, though, this is a good answer.

Comment: Yeah, I copied this from a previous answer of mine.

Comment: I got an error trying to use SublimeREPL so I'm giving up. Thanks though